# Replacement for Entourage on the PC?

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, entourage

At home I've setup my Mac to access work email via Entourage.  For the server name, I entered the webmail address of the Exchange server and Entourage took it from there and everything worked.

Now I am trying to read work email from my Windows 7 laptop.  I tried entering the webmail address into Outlook 2007, but it can't even connect.

Questions:

1. Am I doing it wrong with Outlook?
2. If outlook 2007 isn't capable of this, what other app is available that can handle doing what Entourage is doing for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable exchange over HTTP.
Create the new account
The server is that actual internal name of the exchange server
user name
password
Check Name
IT WILL FAIL THIS IS FINE exit the popup and go to more options
go to connections tab
check Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP
Exchange Proxy Settings
Enter external address to exchange server for URL
Probably uncheck SSL(depends on server settings)
check both on fast and on slow
Prob switch to basic authentication(depends on server settings)

Then Ok out and check name again.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird has some capability of detecting server info automatically.

Outlook will need the correct ports and authentication type set (TLS, SSL, or nothing).